# Inconclusive: Test not run in Xamarin UI Test

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uitest, visual-studio-app-center-test

I have integrated Xamarin UI test within my Xamarin forms App. I am using Xamarin Ui test framework 3.0.0. In the beginning Test was running sucessfully. Now, i am getting error which says ***inconclusive: Test not run*** Error. Can anyone help me with the above issue? Here is the screenshot of the error i am getting.
[image]

Comment: Check your logs

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved the issue . What I did is

```
1. Uninstall nunit framework
2. Unintall xamarin Ui Test framework
3. Reinstall both  Framework
```

Result
Worked as expected
Hope this will help someone who is facing same type of issue.

[image]